# With Covid-19, what governments/societies pose the lowest restrictions for their people?

Tags: covid-19, international

With Sweden being the obvious first choice, I wonder what other (specifically developed countries) governments/societies choose not to react to the virus in the "usual" extent (*i.e.* lock-downs, social isolation).

I am interested in governments/societies that choose to live normally with the risk of the virus. Normal meaning no lock-downs, no forced social isolation, no collective punishments (as in your neighbor has it, you PCR test negative but are still quarantined).

Comment: Covid stringency index https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/covid-stringency-index

Comment: Hi dewid, welcome to Politics! I've edited your question to remove the personal opinion/comments on the suitability of virus restrictions as they are likely to incite opinion-based discussion outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Hi CDJB, I see your point and approve of it, as the question remains textually the same. I just thought a short context would be desired usually.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thanks for the Link, i had a look at the underlying paper, and my interest would be only C1-8 "Containment and closure" (the other reactions being irrelevant as they pose no restrictions). The project seems to intent to collect measures (downside of this approach being that "no measures" are mostly mapped similarly to "no data"), the intention of this question rather being "confirmed absent restrictions". A few country/city names would be enough.

Comment: I don't know if it's *the* lowest, but South Dakota in the US is pretty close: never had a mask mandate, never had a lockdown.  It also has the third-highest new-case rate in the world, the fourth-highest death rate, and both numbers are climbing.